# Tensorflow 2.0: Pre-processing input data generated from ImageDataGenerator before putting to model.fit_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using `ImageDataGenerator` from `tf.keras` (Tensorflow 2.0) to generate data for my training. The raw data contains images and the corresponding segmentation labels (all in RGB format). The sample code with my intuitive approach as below:

```py
....

    # Create two instances with the same arguments
    data_gen_args = dict(
        rotation_range=30,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        validation_split=0.2
    )
  
    image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
    label_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

    # Provide the same seed and keyword arguments to the fit and flow methods
    seed = 2020

    image_train_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        IMAGES_DIR,
        target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
        class_mode=None,
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        seed=seed,
        subset="training")

    label_train_generator = label_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        LABELS_DIR,
        target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
        class_mode=None,
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        seed=seed,
        subset="training")

    # https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13123#issuecomment-529498919
    train_generator = (pair for pair in zip(image_train_generator, label_train_generator))

    image_val_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        IMAGES_DIR,
        target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
        class_mode=None,
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        seed=seed,
        subset="validation")

    label_val_generator = label_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        LABELS_DIR,
        target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
        class_mode=None,
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        seed=seed,
        subset="validation")

    validation_generator = (pair for pair in zip(image_val_generator, label_val_generator))

    model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
        epochs=EPOCHS,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=VADIDATION_STEP)
```

However, I need to pre-process images and labels first before putting it to `fit_generator()`: each image has to be standardized (subtract the `mean` and divided by the `std`), each label has to be converted to the class-wise channel of `numpy.ndarray` (specifically from the shape of `(512, 512, 3)` contains 8 color-labeled segmentation classes to the shape of `(512, 512, 8)` with each channel contains only one segmentation class).

I have tried:

- Pass functions to the `preprocessing_function` arguments in the `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()` → failed because this method required the output has to be the same shape with the input, which is not appropriate to my case.
- Use `list(map(processing_function, batch))` for each batch before putting to `model.fit`:

```py
for e in range(EPOCHS):
        print('Epoch: ', e)
        batches = 0
        for x_batch, y_batch in train_generator:
            x_batch = np.array(list(map(preprocess_input_images, x_batch)))
            y_batch = np.array(list(map(preprocess_input_labels, y_batch)))
            model.fit(x_batch, y_batch)
            batches += 1
            if batches >= STEPS_PER_EPOCH:
                break
```

→ It runs but the results were rubbish (It may behave in the wrong way with my expectation).

- The other thing I'm going to try is making a custom `DataGenerator` or a custom `fit_generator`, inherited from `Keras` class but I'm not sure exactly which approach I should follow.

For now, I'm not quite familiar with `Keras`. So, my question is, with the new `Keras` under `Tensorflow 2.0`, what is the best way to deal with this issue?